# Inkscape Alt + Drag Select not select group members but the Whole group

Tags: select, shortcut, inkscape

I like the Alt + Drag Select in Inkscape, able to select objects in an efficient way.

Sometimes I need to select the whole group the drag path touches, but not it's members,
Any one know is there some options to activate to do this kind of operation ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not currently possible in Inkscape.